# Summing lists of different lengths in Python beginning at a specified index using a function

Tags: python, list, function, indexing, python-itertools

How can I combine multiple lists starting at a specified index within one of the lists, while also summing the values at the respective indexes?

If I had 3 lists:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0]
b = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
c = [5, 2]
```

How could I make it so that I could insert lists `b` and `c` into any position within `a`, and the respective indexes would sum?

For example, I could insert list `b` starting from the first index of `a`, and also insert list `c` starting from the fifth index of `a`. The output of this would look something like:

```
NewList = [1, 4, 6, 8, 10, *11*, 2, 0, 0]
```

You can see that when adding lists `b` and `c` at the aforementioned indexes of `a`, there was an overlap at the fifth index, which I would like to do.

I have tried using `izip_longest` from `itertools` in combination with a slicing method:

```
result = [sum(n) for n in izip_longest(a[2:], b, fillvalue=0)]
```

But this produces:

```
result = [5, 7, 9, 5, 6, 0, 0]
```

This cuts off the zero and one index in list `a`, which I do not want. However, I want to use `izip_longest` because I can sum lists with different lengths.

I would like to create a function that does this with an arbitrary amount of lists, so `a` could be a list with len = 1000 and I could insert any amount of different lists with different lengths wherever I want into `a`, as many times as I want and the index values would sum.

Comment: As mentioned in the edit proposal. `[b]` is not the same as `b`. Don't confuse these two.

Comment: I suggest you simplify your question. I admit I only read it once, but it's hard to understand what your point is.

Comment: Why you do not do it line by line first? It takes time to perfection [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). I do not think this would be easy (or possible) using list comprehension. In other words, **there is not a one line solution for this**.

Comment: @GrzegorzOledzki My end goal is to plot a signal (for example a sine wave) and then have the ability to insert additional signals into that main signal at whichever location I choose. So I wanted to append these signals into lists, manipulate them by adding additional signals, and then plot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a function that should do what you're asking for:

```
def combine(lista, listb, index_in_list_a_to_start_insert):
    # left pad list b with zeros
    newb = [0]*index_in_list_a_to_start_insert + listb

    # right pad shorter list
    max_len = max(len(lista), len(newb))
    newa = lista if len(lista) >= max_len else lista + [0]*(max_len-len(lista))
    newb = newb if len(newb) >= max_len else newb + [0]*(max_len-len(newb))

    # sum element-wise            
    return [a + b for a, b in zip(newa,newb)]
```

You can run your example by chaining this function as so:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0]
b = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
c = [5, 2]
combine(combine(a, b, 1), c, 5)
```

Output:

```
 [1, 4, 6, 8, 10, 11, 2, 0, 0]
```

You'd probably also want to add some error checking to make sure that the specified index is in-bounds.

Comment: Would you know how to keep the size of the original list? For example, if I added b into list a at index 6 using your combine function, the output of adding a and b together would be [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 2, 3, 4]. So len(a) would have the same value before and after the function.

Comment: Instead of right padding the shorter list, truncate `newb` so that it is no  longer than `a`.

Comment: Or you can truncate at the end: `newlist = combine(a, b, 6)[0:len(a)]`